# MvvmCross IMvxGeoLocationWatcher never fires MvxGeoLocation success

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using the MvvmCross Location plugin.  On some devices, the MvxGeoLocation success fires, on others it never does.  I have seen other similar questions with answers ([MVVMCross IMvxGeoLocationWatcher Success Action never fires on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703427/mvvmcross-imvxgeolocationwatcher-success-action-never-fires-on-android)).  However, this is not working on all devices (rebooting), so the solution is not valid.  The device I'm testing on right now is on Android V 4.0.3, HTC Vivid.  The client is reporting the same issue on their devices.  Below is my LocationService code, the OnLocation method is never firing on these devices.

```
public class LocationService : ILocationService
{
    private readonly IMvxGeoLocationWatcher _locationWatcher;
    private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public bool HasLocation()
    {
        return (Latitude != 0.0 && Longitude != 0.0);
    }

    public LocationService(IMvxGeoLocationWatcher locationWatcher, IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        _locationWatcher = locationWatcher;
        _messenger = messenger;
        _locationWatcher.Start(new MvxGeoLocationOptions(){ EnableHighAccuracy = true}, OnLocation, OnError);
    }

    private void OnError(MvxLocationError error)
    {
        _messenger.Publish(new GpsUnavailableMessage(this));
    }

    private void OnLocation(MvxGeoLocation location)
    {
        Latitude = location.Coordinates.Latitude;
        Longitude = location.Coordinates.Longitude;

        var message = new LocationMessage(this, location.Coordinates.Latitude, location.Coordinates.Longitude);
        _messenger.Publish(message);
    }
}
```

Here are the messages showing in LogCat, does this look like I'm getting a GPS location?

```
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): SV count: 9 ephemerisMask: 93d5 almanacMask: 93d5
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 1 snr: 0.0 elev: 7.0 azimuth: 146.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 3 snr: 0.0 elev: 33.0 azimuth: 49.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 5 snr: 0.0 elev: 0.0 azimuth: 0.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 7 snr: 0.0 elev: 74.0 azimuth: 351.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 8 snr: 0.0 elev: 43.0 azimuth: 314.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 9 snr: 0.0 elev: 36.0 azimuth: 312.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 10 snr: 0.0 elev: 0.0 azimuth: 0.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 13 snr: 0.0 elev: 39.0 azimuth: 188.0 E A
07-31 11:54:59.883: V/GpsLocationProvider(246): sv: 16 snr: 0.0 elev: 1.0 azimuth: 66.0 E A
```

So is this an Mono for android problem?  The following code never triggers the ILocationListener:

```
    [Register("requestLocationUpdates", "(Ljava/lang/String;JFLandroid/location/LocationListener;)V", "GetRequestLocationUpdates_Ljava_lang_String_JFLandroid_location_LocationListener_Handler")]
    public virtual void RequestLocationUpdates(string provider, long minTime, float minDistance, ILocationListener listener);
```

Comment: It doesn't feel like this is an mvvm issue - sounds like it's just android and/or Xamarin.Android - the mvx GPS plugin is a pretty thin wrapper really.

Comment: thanks stuart.. you are right, this was a xamarin issue.. had to completely uninstall then install xamarin.android 4.8 fresh.. problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with Xamarin.Android when upgrading.  Uninstalling Xamarin.Android completely and then reinstalling v 4.8 solved the issue.